# Multilingual site with different domain

Tags: i18n-l10n

Is it possible to make multilingual site with each language has own domain? So I want to manage all domains with one code and database. All languages will be exactly same translated content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite possible to do. But there may be some cases where you need to do some custom code. That also totally depends on your business requirement.

However, please follow this one [How to set different languages for different domains, and display the language switcher accordingly?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11752/how-to-set-different-languages-for-different-domains-and-display-the-language-s)


In Drupal 7 [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module is the best one to make multi domain sites. This has a helper module called [Domain Locale](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_locale) which is what you need I guess from the question asked.